# A verb for a job prospect that is getting worse?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> The prospect of finding a job in this field is —————— .

I am looking for a verb for the above sentence to mean the prospect is ‘getting worse’ or ‘worsening’. That is, it is getting harder and harder to find job in this field. Should I just go with ‘getting worse’ or ‘worsening’. What about ‘declining’? Do you know a better choice?

Comment: Close-voters should explain their reasons. This is a typical word-request question.

Comment: Prospects are "dwindling" was my initial instinct.

Answer (score 2):

“The prospect of job” should be “the prospect of a job.” I suggest *declining* to fill in your blank.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *receding*. My dictionary (Chambers, 11th Edn) defines *recede* thiswise:

> to go back, go father off, become more distant (lit and fig)

that is, both literally and figuratively, and this latter point is why I suggest the word.  The original sentence makes figurative use of the word *prospect* and one might imagine "the prospect receding into the distance".

While I'm answering, I'd also suggest correcting OP's sentence by inserting *a*, like this:

> The prospect of a job in this field is receding.

Answer (score 1):

> The prospect of a job in this field is **going downhill**.

OED: **downhill**

> 2. figurative and in figurative contexts. **Into a steadily deteriorating state or worsening situation**. Frequently in **to go downhill:** to get worse.
>
> 1949   Long Beach (Calif.) Independent 28 Aug. 14/1   *It starts a vicious circle of deflation that can spiral downhill much faster than inflation spiraled uphill.*
>
> 2003   N.Y. Times 20 July ix. 6/4   *Ms. Couric introduced her guest as a ‘right-wing telebimbo’, and things went downhill from there.*

Answer (score 0):

It's not a single word, but ***grow bleak*** would go very well in the sentence:

> The prospect of *being employed*/ *finding a job* in this field is ***growing bleak.***

Bleak is often used to describe a future without much hope:

> not hopeful or encouraging
>
> - a *bleak* prognosis
> - a *bleak* outlook
> - the future looks *bleak* ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bleak))

> If a situation is bleak, there is little or no hope for the future:
>
> - The economic outlook is *bleak*. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bleak))

Otherwise ***fade*** could be an option. It means to:

> gradually grow faint and disappear ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=fade%20meaning&source=hp&ei=rz3JY4btMYzngAbF4qrQDw&iflsig=AK50M_UAAAAAY8lLv0aLB5XZQhZxgYbMDKFjXKqnKmIA&oq=fade%20mea&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADINCAAQgAQQsQMQRhD5ATIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDoRCC4QgwEQxwEQsQMQ0QMQgAQ6CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOggILhCxAxCDAToICAAQgAQQsQM6CwguEIAEEMcBENEDOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoLCC4QgAQQsQMQgwE6DgguEIAEELEDEMcBENEDOggILhCABBCxAzoOCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQ1AI6DgguEIAEELEDEMcBEK8BOgsILhCABBDHARCvAToLCC4QrwEQxwEQgARQAFjvEmCdGmgAcAB4AIABaYgBowWSAQM3LjGYAQCgAQE&sclient=gws-wiz))